# How to view the recently deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers

I thought there was an answer to this question, but it seems to be deleted. How to view the deleted answer? many thanks! [Prove or disprove $SO(4n) \supseteq \frac{(Sp(1)\times Sp(n))}{\mathbb{Z}_2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4123537/79069)

To view the deleted answer, do I need to have enough reputations?

Comment: Yes, see @Jose's answer below.  Also, a user deletes an answer for a reason; they want to spend more time on it, or they realized they made an error, or the for some reason decide to remove their post.  We can't know, and seeing it, even though deleted, won't necessarily answer that question. In any case, let's honor the decision of the answerer.

Comment: There could have been a deleted comment perhaps. No amount of reputation lets you see those (but e.g. mods can still see them)

Answer (score 2):

That question has no deleted answers. Being able to see deleted posts is something that you get when your reputation reaches $10\,000$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).